# optional constructor with initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++14, option-type, c++17

What is the purpose of this special constructor taking initializer list. Can someone give an example of when this will be useful?

```
template <class U, class... Args>
constexpr explicit optional(in_place_t, initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args);
```

How is the above different from this?

```
template <class... Args> 
constexpr explicit optional(in_place_t, Args&&... args);
```

Ref: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html#optional.object.ctor

P.S. Not sure whether to use c++14 or c++1z tag. I think there should be tag for c++ techinical specification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the two separate constructors is to allow construction of objects that take an `initializer_list` as their constructor argument (optionally followed by an arbitrary list of arguments). Say you have a type `foo` that looks like this:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};
```

In the absence of the constructor

```
template <class U, class... Args>
constexpr explicit optional(in_place_t, initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args);
```

you wouldn't be able to construct an `optional` as

```
optional<foo> o(in_place, {1, 2, 3});
```

The above fails because a *braced-init-list* has no type, so template argument deduction fails. You'd have to resort to something like this:

```
auto il = {1, 2, 3};
optional<foo> o(in_place, il);
```

Having the constructor that accepts the `initializer_list` argument allows a more natural syntax when constructing the `optional` object.

Here's a [minimal example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4a7136fd37e4ab) demonstrating the utility of the two constructors.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't the same explanation apply to `vector.emplace_back`?

Comment: @balki Absolutely, and that the reason why you can't do `std::vector<foo>().emplace_back({1,2,3})` but `std::vector<foo>().emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3})` succeeds.

Comment: I understand the technical reason. But not why special effort is made for initializer list support in some parts but not in others.

Comment: @balki I have no way of knowing for sure, but it could've been an oversight. Both the `emplace` functions and list-initialization were new to C++11, and it could be that no one thought of this particular situation. Also keep in mind that containers must delegate to allocators for the construction of new elements. Maybe something about allocators makes this difficult to implement. Or it might just be waiting for a new proposal to be submitted, because it looks like the addition of an `emplace(_back)` overload with a similar signature as the one above would be a backwards compatible change.

Comment: Thinking about this again, the special case of `initializer_list` is just an unnecessary hack. If the type has a constructor that takes two `initializer_list`s, it breaks again. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d8gX-B

Comment: @balki Yes, of course it breaks if the constructor has two `initializer_list` parameters, but it's a safe bet that such constructors are a lot more uncommon compared to those that take a single `initializer_list`. So the `optional` overload in question fixes the common use case. If you need to deal with two or more, construct them explicitly `optional<bar> o(in_place_t{}, {1, 2, 3}, std::initializer_list<char>{'a', 'b', 'c'});`